# Como resolver logo sendo exibido pela metade

Tags: css

Tenho uma página onde estou posicionando a `logo` da empresa, o posicionamento está ficando correto, mas o mesmo está sendo exibido `cortado` já revi meu `css` e não consegui resolver, o que estou fazendo é mostrar a `logo` com um tamanho maior quando a página não rolar e um imagem menor quando houver a rolagem, fiz isso até o momento:

CSS da logo e do scrolling:

```
.logo { 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0px;
    width:185px;
    z-index:10000;

}

.large-logo {display:block;}
.scrolling-logo {display:none;}
.scrolling .large-logo {display:none;}
.scrolling .scrolling-logo {display:block;}

.navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    padding: 27px 0;
    margin: 0!important;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

A div da logo está assim:

```
          <div class="logo img-responsive col-md-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand large-logo" href="index.php"><img src="images/anc.fw.png" /></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand scrolling-logo" href="index.php"><img src="images/anc.small.fw.png" /></a>          
      </div>
```

Tenho um `.js` vinculado:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 30 ) {
      $('.logo').addClass('scrolling');
    } else {
      $('.logo').removeClass('scrolling');
  }
});
```

A página do projeto pode ser visualizada aqui:
[Projeto](http://ancestofados.com.br/anc/index.php)

Comment: Gostaria de saber porque minha pergunta foi negativada algum problema com ela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas divs por cima do teu logotipo, por isso está cortando.
Veja isso aplicando um float:right nas seguintes divs:

- O menu .navbar .navbar-default .navbar-top
- No container abaixo do    menu
- E no .navbar-collapse .collapse

Um snippet que eu sempre uso nesses casos é esse:

```
[].forEach.call($$("*"),function(a){a.style.outline="1px solid #"+(~~(Math.random()*(1<<24))).toString(16)})
```

Ele coloca um outline em todos os elementos o que facilita a visualização de possíveis sobreposições.

Comment: Olá @haykou, obrigado pela excelente dica, estou vendo agora as divs.

Comment: O teste me mostrou que a .navbar-header está encobrindo a logo, mas as tentativas que fiz foram insuficientes, alguma dica?

Comment: @adventistapr , conseguiu resolver? entrei no teu link e o logo está normal

Comment: Olá @haykou, pode me dar mais uma ajuda, como posso deixar o texto do primeiro menu mais abaixo, centralizado verticalmente?

Comment: @adventistapr position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    resize: vertical;    ,ai voce acerta o alinhamento horizontal usando o right/left: "porcentagem"

Comment: Olá @haykou, peço perdão pela minha ignorância no assunto, mas onde aplico essas configurações indicadas? Agradeço pela dica, novamente.